# Will global variables be aligned to a 4 bytes boundary?

Tags: windows, assembly, x86, nasm, memory-alignment

I am reading about data alignment. And I know that when an x86 program starts executing, its stack will be aligned to a 4 bytes boundary. But will the .data and .bss sections also be aligned to a 4 bytes boundary? For example if I have the following:

```
section .data
    number1 DW 1234
```

When a program with this code executes, will number1 always be on an address that is divisible by 4?

Comment: If, by "x86", you mean Intel/AMD 32-bit or 64-bit processors (which is a fairly common usage), then keep in mind that alignment is probably different in the 64-bit case, as well. Although something aligned to 8- or 16-byte boundaries is trivially also aligned on a 4-byte boundary...

Comment: @twalberg I meant on 32-bit processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. See the [nasm manual](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.06/html/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.9.2):

> The defaults assumed by NASM if you do not specify the above
> qualifiers are:
>
> section .data progbits  alloc   noexec  write    align=4
>
> section .bss     nobits    alloc   noexec  write    align=4

Notice it says `align=4`. This is for ELF output. You have forgotten to specify what you use.

For the win32 format, the relevant part is [section 7.5.1](http://www.nasm.us/xdoc/2.11.06/html/nasmdoc7.html#section-7.5.1):

> The defaults assumed by NASM if you do not specify the above
> qualifiers are:
>
> section .data    data  align=4
>
> section .bss     bss   align=4